# Please help me figure out the best way to talk about "negligence"

Tags: grammar

Please check the sentences below.

*1. I think the greatest negligence in these years was the loss of
    opportunity to develop its own line of products.*

*2. I think the greatest negligence in these years was its failure to
    develop its own line of products.*

**Q)** Which one is better? (please explain your answer a bit).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. (it) refers to a hardware company(Samsung) that has not developed any software product through these years.

Comment: The two sentences don't mean the same exact thing. What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: By "better" I mean which one does sound more natural.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "better" form with such lack of context. For example: "failure" implies Samsung tried and failed. "Loss of opportunity" implies they didn't bother to develop and missed the chance.

Comment: *Negligence* means neglecting to perform some required act. A *loss* may result from *negligence*, but it is not itself negligent. *Failure* suits much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like version #2 better than #1. Number one is just too wordy, with its redundant "loss of opportunity."  However, I recommend re-wording #2 as follows:

> I think the greatest negligence in these years was its failure to develop its own product line.

In providing a context, as JMB did, above, the American English form of the sentence would be as follows:

> I think Samsung's greatest negligence in these years was its failure to develop its own product line.

In British English, the sentence would be as follows:

> I think Samsung's greatest negligence in these years was their failure to develop their own product line.

[Increasingly, I like the British custom of making the name of a company, such as Samsung, a plural noun or plural pronoun, since a company or corporation, after all,  consists of living people! In America, on the other hand, a company is considered an entity, an "it." In legal, contractual terms in America, a company is also considered **a** singular "person." Occasionally, however, the pronoun *whose* can substitute for a company's name, such as in "IBM, whose third-quarter earnings rose 26 percent last year, seems to be on the ascendancy."]

Comment: Thank you. I prefer to use a plural pronoun for a company too but I wasn't sure about it.